# soapui property transfer does not execute in test case

Tags: soapui

I m using free soapui v5

My transfer property executes well when I run it alone, but when I execute in a whole test case, soapui says all runs fine whereas I checked and that's not true value in target didn't change like when I executed alone.

Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to post more details on how your test case appears and what steps are involved?

Alternatively you may set the value to property of the test case and access in the later steps. And this link can help you
https://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/10-groovy-scripts-on-your-finger-tips-soapui/

- If the later step is a request step you can access it as

  `${#TestCase#PROPERTY_NAME}`
- If the later step is a groovy step you can access it as

  `context.expand('${#TestCase#PROPERTY_NAME}')`